# Atom Editor : Failed to spawn command `ansible-lint`

Tags: windows, path, ansible, lint

I'm trying to use Ansible Lint plugin for Atom editor in Windows 10. Unfortunately I'm getting the following error:

```
An unexpected error with ansible, ansible-lint, linter-ansible-linting, atom, linter, and/or your playbook, has occurred.
Failed to spawn command `ansible-lint`. Make sure `ansible-lint` is installed and on your PATH
```

Can you please advise, where should I include the path ? And should I include the lib directory or the mail for lint ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, Ansible Lint for Atom requires ansible-lint package in Python. And this package, installs Ansible itself (via pip) and this doesn't work on Windows. So Ansible-Lint won't work on Windows, as far as i know. It might work in the Linux subsystem, but then Atom won't work in that.
I am also in fact looking for an Ansible linter or YML syntax checker, without having to install ansible itself on the machine (Windows)